# java наводка на кнопку

Tags: java

[image: ...]

Имею такое вот окошко, мне необходимо чтобы когда курсор был наведён на нижнюю кнопку "Выйти", то оно подсвечивалось и на него можно было нажать...
С кнопкой продолжить я это сделал с помощью такого:

```
if(GamePanel.mouseX > GamePanel.WIDTH / 2 - buttonWidthContinue/ 2 && GamePanel.mouseX < GamePanel.WIDTH / 2 + buttonWidthContinue / 2 && GamePanel.mouseY > GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2 - buttonHeightContinue / 2 && GamePanel.mouseY < GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2 + buttonHeightContinue / 2){
            transP = 60; //Подсветка
            if (GamePanel.leftMouse){
                GamePanel.state = GamePanel.STATES.PLAY;
            }
        } else {
            transP = 0; // Удаление подсветки
        }
```

Но вот как с нижней кнопкой сделать понятия не имею, если что то не понятно, то обращайтесь...

Comment: Ну точно так же.

Comment: Это не ответ...

Comment: А ты гений! Говорить по комментарий, что это не ответ, требует недюжинного ума. А на пробовал свой ум применить к тому, что я написал?

Answer (score 0):

Если кнопка представляет из себя объект Button (или JButton), то тогда стоит добавить ActionListener, чтобы обрабатывать нажатия от клаиватуры и мыши.
Если же эти кнопки просто нарисованы (что скорее всего так), то аналогично первой кнопке, обработать и вторую кнопку.
Рекомендую использовать объекты, пусть даже и созданные самостоятельно, чем нарисованные решения, потому что с ними намного проще контактировать, например, вынести всю логику нажатия в метод isPressed() и избавиться от дублирования кода.

Comment: Пойми, что точно так же - не ответ, мне нужно решение: цифорки, формулы там...

Comment: @doctorspiele тогда тебе стоило бы рассказать как именно у тебя расположены кнопки и их координаты, тогда и возможно получить цифры

Comment: Ну цифры это слишком, достаточно формулы... 
`
buttonWidthExit = 230;//Ширина 
buttonHeightExit = 60; //Высота
GamePanel.WIDTH = 600;
GamePanel.HEIGHT = 600;
`
Размещена нижняя кнопка по:
`
GamePanel.WIDTH / 2 - buttonWidthExit/ 2,GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2 + buttonHeightExit, buttonWidthExit,buttonHeightExit
`

GamePanel = Ширина/Высота окна...
button = Координаты рисунков